# Window ErrorLog not visible in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

Possibly a really stupid question but I had a IDE issue where I had to re-install eclipse ADT bundle
and now I cannot see the Error log. I have looked under Window-Show View-Other and cannot find a ref to error log.

Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are referring to the view called "Problems", which is there in the Window -> Show View menu.

The other views that show errors are "Console" and "LogCat".

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

Use keyboard shortcut Alt-Shift-Q and Q to bring up Show View dialog, type "error" , it will filter out and show you "Error Log", double-click on it to get to "Error Log"

Comment: On a mac I tried alt command Q and brings up same options as Window-Show View- but no sign of any error log.

Comment: Try quick access shortcut "CTRL 3" and type "error log". Click on Show View(Error Log) under commands.